# Connecting a client pc to a server pc via an ethernet cable? (java)

Tags: java, server, client

Currently the setup I have is the client code is on my laptop, which is hooked up to an embedded box PC which will run the server code.

I've tested the client/server interaction running both the client code and server code on my laptop, and can confirm they run together. However I'm stuck as how to proceed and adapt my code from what it is now. If I understand correctly, the Server sets up an IP address and the client looks for it and connects to it?

Currently this the code I have converted to on the sever side (The commented out section is what was in place when I was running it on my laptop)

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress); 
server = new ServerSocket(SOCKET_PORT, 1, ip); //SOCKET_PORT = 8010

//server = new ServerSocket(SOCKET_PORT); //SOCKET_PORT = 8010
```

Would this be considered to be the right way to go about doing things on the server side?

As for the client I'm still quite confused.. so far this is the code I had implemented for when I had the code ruinning on the same device...

(I have a loop that spins off clients into separate threads when they connect to the server)

```
//Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", port);
```

And then here is the code I think it will convert to, but I may be wrong here

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ipAddress, port);
```

I appreciate any help, even if it's just helping to describe the general process of an IP connection between server/client on different devices

Answer (score 0):

I would think you just have to connect the devices, look up the IPs (probably using the command line) and replace the IP addresses with those IPs.